# How to stop ARC from releasing twice an object shared by by 2 threads?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, automatic-ref-counting

Our application experiences a double release crash in a library that we wrote that is ARC enabled. After running instrumentation, we discovered that the double release happens on an object that is accessed by 2 threads.

The object in question is first allocated outside the 2 threads in an initialization method

```
objectX = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:barcodeBytes length:sizeof(barcodeBytes)];
```

Thread A is started and it adds objectX to an NSDictionary.

Thread B assignes ObjectX to a local NSData pointer and removes ObjectX from the shared NSDictionary using removeObjectAtIndex

What we have noticed through running NSZombie is that ObjectX is now being autoreleased twice. It seems that one release is being issued directly on the object, and another release is done indirectly when the NSDictionary that is containing it is released.

First Release:

```
   0 libobjc.A.dylib -[NSObject release]
   1 libobjc.A.dylib (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*)
   2 libobjc.A.dylib (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::tls_dealloc(void*)
   3 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_tsd_cleanup
   4 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_exit
   5 libsystem_pthread.dylib pthread_exit
   6 Foundation +[NSThread exit]
   7 TestApp 0x348e72
   8 Foundation __NSThread__main__
   9 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body
  10 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_start
  11 libsystem_pthread.dylib thread_start
```

Second Release:

```
   0 libobjc.A.dylib -[NSObject release]
   1 CoreFoundation CFRelease
   2 CoreFoundation -[__NSDictionaryM dealloc]
   3 libobjc.A.dylib objc_object::sidetable_release(bool)
   4 libobjc.A.dylib -[NSObject release]
   5 libobjc.A.dylib (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*)
   6 libobjc.A.dylib (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::tls_dealloc(void*)
   7 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_tsd_cleanup
   8 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_exit
   9 libsystem_pthread.dylib pthread_exit
  10 Foundation +[NSThread exit]
  11 TestApp 0x348e72
  12 Foundation __NSThread__main__
  13 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_body
  14 libsystem_pthread.dylib _pthread_start
  15 libsystem_pthread.dylib thread_start
```

The end result is that ObjectX is released double as much as it should have and we see a crash. Interestingly, we are only seeing this on arm64 devices.

Answer (score 0):

You implicitly also retain the object when you store it in both threads, so the release count matches. Rather, I would look if you are messing up the thread fencing somewhere, especially if you aren't using GCD. Keep in mind, ARM is a weakly ordered architecture so it is much easier to get into memory ordering issues than on say x86.

Answer (score 0):

> Thread A is started and it adds objectX to an NSDictionary.
>
> Thread B assignes ObjectX to a local NSData pointer and it removes ObjectX from the shared NSDictionary

But there's your problem right there. You have two objects, `objectX` and the dictionary, that are being touched by two different threads. That is a serious danger, and if you don't know exactly what you are doing and how to take the appropriate precautions, you shouldn't do it at all.

Comment: You do not share any info about your code, so it is impossible to say more. The devil is in the details, and you give no details at all. There are ways to handle passing / sharing an object between threads, but who knows whether you are using them?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your synchronization code for the dictionary its hard to tell. If the data is immutable you can create a copy in the second thread. That would ensure that it is a different object than from the dictionary being removed.

Also make sure that when you are mutating the dictionary, all of the read threads are waiting.